# How to debug when the USB is set to "CHARGING ONLY" mode

Tags: usb-debugging, android-10, nokia

- Device: Nokia 2.2
- Carrier: Airtel
- Android version: 10
- Root status: Never rooted

I've set a PIN lock to my phone and forgot the password.. luckily I've turned on the USB debugging mode earlier but I didn't set the USB behaviour to PTP or MTP, It's still in the charging only mode. The phone's not allowing to change the USB behaviour to PTP unless I unlock my phone which I literally cannot do.

Is there anyway to change the USB behaviour to PTP, so that I can use ADB to recover call lists and app data from my phone?

Comment: If you would have set the USB mode to MTP before has no effect in your case as MTP will only be active if the device has been unlocked at least once. Before your files can't be accessed because they are encrypted using File Based Encryption (FBE).

Comment: Do you think I can use adb for data recovery no matter what mode of USB behaviour it is..???

Comment: If your phone is really encrypted (which should be the case by default for Android 10) then it does not matter if you could access the phone, the user data files remain encrypted after reboot unless you have entered the correct PIN or somehow manages to unlock the phone (e.g. via Google remote find my device?).

Comment: Tell me which other ways can I use to unlock my device.. I'm trying the Google remote find my device now..

Comment: I just tried the Google's find my device.. but the tool aims to wipe all my data.. could you tell me any other way around please.

Comment: The only way left I know is to try to enter the PIN multiple times. On some device then an option occurs to unlock the device using the Google account password instead. Make sure the device is online while you do this. But this is the last way I know.

Comment: Okay #Robert, thnx for your time.